# sqlalchemy joinedload does not link back child to parent. parent.childen[0].parent is not loaded

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

my model is simple. a child has a parent. a parent has children.

```
Parent
      Child
```

I use this query to joinload

```
q = session.query(Parent).options(joinedload(Parent.children))
```

I also use `session.expire_on_commit=False` because I need to access objects outside of scope of session.

The problem is that when I refer to parent from a child, the parent is not joinedload:

```
parent.children[0].parent # this raises error outside session scope.
```

Error is this:

```
Parent instance <Parent at 0x117d95310> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'parent' cannot proceed
```

How can I solve this? (I expected the sqlalchemy links child to parent on joinedload)

---

Edited to add example:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")

from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Then I create some objects:

```
with session_scope() as session:
    p = Parent()
    ch1 = Child()
    ch1.parent=p
    ch2 = Child()
    ch2.parent=p
    session.add(p)
    session.add(ch1)
    session.add(ch2)
```

then I query parents with joinedload of children and I set expire_on_commit to False:

```
with session_scope() as session:
    session.expire_on_commit = False
    p_all = session.query(Parent).options(subqueryload(Parent.children)).all()
```

it works when I query the children of parent:

```
p_all[0].children # -> [<__main__.Child at 0x10a857810>, <__main__.Child at 0x10ba89e10>]
p_all[0].children[0] # -> <__main__.Child at 0x10a857810>
```

but then I want to access the parent through child and it gives error:

```
p_all[0].children[0].parent # -> Error
# DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Child at 0x10a857810> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'parent' cannot proceed
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Can you share minimal models and code to reproduce this behaviour  (including relationships)?

Comment: You may want to try using `containseager` and manually configuring the join: `session.query(Parent).join(Parent.children).options(containseager(Parent.children))`

Comment: You probably also need to make sure to be using `backref`, or better yet, `back_populates` and define the relationship on both sides

Comment: added example. also tried `containseager` does not solve or change error. as you can see in example i use `back_populates`. @StephenFuhry @snakecharmerb